# Cut a file delimited on a number with one or more digits

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, perl, cut

I'm looking for a way to extract the first column of a text file that has no specific delimiters except for arbitrary digits that begin the next column. Example:

```
John Smith 1234 Main Street
Amy Brown and Sally Williams 9 Drury Lane
Sunny's 1000 Brown Avenue
```

Expected output would be:

```
John Smith
Amy Brown and Sally Williams
Sunny's
```

It appears that `cut` doesn't support functionality such as `cut file.txt -d {0..9} -f 1`

Solutions can use any standard unix utility.

Comment: Line 2 doesn't have multi digits.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[0-9]' '{ print $1 }' file
John Smith
Amy Brown and Sally Williams
Sunny's
```

With `-F'[0-9]'` we say that digits are to be considered field separators in the input data, and with `print $1` we output the first digit-separated field.

Change `-F'[0-9]'` to `-F' *[0-9]'` to also get rid of any spaces before the digit.

Answer (score 5):

And a `sed` solution:

```
echo "John Smith 1234 Main Street
Amy Brown and Sally Williams 9 Drury Lane
Sunny's 1000 Brown Avenue" | sed 's/ *[0-9].*$//'
John Smith 
Amy Brown and Sally Williams 
Sunny's
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`

```
grep -o '^[^[:digit:]]*' file
```

(note that it won't output anything for lines like `123foo`, that is lines where the part left of the digits is empty).

Answer (score 1):

GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '.*?(?=\s*\d)' file
```